# If I upgrade Foundation V3 to V4 will V3 projects still compile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation V3 currently. Does anybody know if I upgrade Foundation V3 to V4 will V3 projects still compile using V3 gems/sass? Can the two versions of Foundation be used on the same computer for different projects or will I have to migrate all my existing projects to V4 if I upgrade?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [migration guideline documented](http://foundation.zurb.com/migration.php) in Zurb's website. Your design will not change, at least it should not be, as things still work pretty much the same. But you will certainly have to change some markups. Take for example the classes for the grid which is, arguably, Foundation's heart.

About using different versions, yes I think it should work as long as you only use a specific version for one project, it doesn't matter if they are on a single computer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Von. How does Foundation know which Ruby Gem to use? Is the Foundation version referenced in the project? I am assuming that if I do nothing to my existing projects they will use the Foundation 3 Ruby Gem and I won't have to change any markup? Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: [See this link](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) and go to the section "Running multiple versions".